# Why is a css transformation rough and flickering on some Windows machines?

Tags: css, animation, gpu, transformation

I have a CSS Transformation very similar to this example

http://codepen.io/ewe/pen/tDJLr

The whole animation happens via css3 transform.

```
.item {
    .animation(item 10s ease-in-out infinite);
}

@-webkit-keyframes item {
  0%,100%{ -webkit-transform:translateY(0) rotate(-6deg);}
  50%{ -webkit-transform:translateY(-20px) rotate(8deg); }
}
@-moz-keyframes item {
  0%,100%{ -moz-transform:translateY(0) rotate(-6deg);}
  50%{ -moz-transform:translateY(-20px) rotate(8deg); }
}
@-o-keyframes item {
  0%,100%{ -o-transform:translateY(0) rotate(-6deg);}
  50%{ -o-transform:translateY(-20px) rotate(8deg); }
}
@keyframes item {
  0%,100%{ transform:translateY(0) rotate(-6deg);}
  50%{ transform:translateY(-20px) rotate(8deg); }
}
```

This works fine and smooth in a modern browser on my mac.

Css transform should also work in IE10 and 11 out of the box according to http://caniuse.com/transforms2d

But on my client's IE11 or in any browser on my virtual machine, the animated items flicker a little on the border and the animation is not smooth.

Rotated or scaled text wobbles.

And also, the Ventilation gears up immediately like hell when running im my VM.

Shouldn't the CSS transformation go through the GPU and thus be smooth and quiet and cool?!

Or could it be that neither my client's low end laptop nor my VM *has* a GPU?

Is there a way to either avoid that, smoothen the transformation via a js polyfill, or simply disable it on devices that can't handle it well?

Comment: Works fine here in IE 11 on my desktop computer.  I would suggest that it's some combination of poor implementation in IE and lack of appropriate acceleration hardware on your target computers.  Many low-end laptops have very simplified GPU that IE may not be using or may not have enough capability to handle this.  I have no idea about your VM.

Comment: And there's no way to sniff the hardware from the browser, is there? I've seen http://blog.lunarlogic.io/2013/force-gpu-powered-css-transitions-in-webkit/, but that's not very helpful either. The associated example http://jsfiddle.net/dotmariusz/kYZ9P/ is as rough (most of all the transformed text) as in my own case

Comment: It is a bit tough to sniff this type of thing with feature detection.  I have seen some cases where using a 3d operation (even though you don't need it) causes the browser to use the GPU when it wouldn't have otherwise, but I have no idea if that would help here.  Could you replace the whole thing with an animated gif?

Comment: Yes that's the example in the link above. But it's more directed towards css transition, not transform. A gif... well why not flash then haha... no, maybe it's a quite a straightforward idea. I thought about trying raphael.js first as an alternative too though.